# FATAL: database does not exist in postgresql for jdbc

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I create a database by installing Postgres on my ubuntu 20.04 machine and used the following commands to create it:

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
CREATE USER preopus WITH PASSWORD 'admin222';
CREATE DATABASE preopusDB WITH OWNER=preopus;
```

and received no errors. When I tried using slick-codegen by calling the database with this URL:
`"jdbc:postgresql://localhost/preopusDB?user=preopus&password=admin222"`, it gave me the error:

> [error] (run-main-0) org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "preopusDB" does not exist

If anybody can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use `preopusdb` (all lowercase)  in the URL?

Comment: Duh. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) mentioned, the database name (and possibly other parameter values) in the JDBC URL are case-sensitive. But any unquoted identifier like `preopusDB` in your `CREATE DATABASE` statement will be folded to lower case.

Use

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost/preopusdb?user=...
```